# extracting values from multiple xmls in a directory and placing them in xls worksheet

Tags: xml, xslt, excel, xslt-1.0, vba

I am a newbie with xslt. My problem is something like this:

I have a directory in which a number of xml documents are stored. These documents contain similar node structures. What I need to do now is to write a stylesheet to extract a set of elements like date, amount, system etc from each of these xmls and put them in an excel sheet (preferably in form of a table.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You haven't asked any question. The transformation is trivial to write, provided meaningful and specific requirements. The XSLT function `document()` can be used to provide the document-node of an XML document given the URI (including file URI) of the document.

Answer (score 2):

With VBA on Windows you should be able [to automate](http://manual.altova.com/AltovaXML/altovaxmlcommunity/index.html?axcominterface.htm) [AltovaXML](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) and use its XSLT 2.0 [collection function](http://manual.altova.com/AltovaXML/altovaxmlcommunity/index.html?fnfunctionssupport.htm) to access all XML files in a directory and process them.

If you really want to use XSLT 1,0 to process several files in a directory then you need to feed your XSLT 1.0 processor an XML document that lists the files e.g. you need to build a file `dir.xml`

```
<files>
  <file>doc1.xml</file>
  <file>doc2.xml</file>
</files>
```

then you can use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="document(document('dir.xml')/files/file))//foo"/>` to process the `foo` elements in all files.